# login to Facebook without user interaction

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, server-side, facebook-authentication

I would like to perform the login procedure to Facebook on my server using python script :
when I start my server he logs on to facebook using my private account. (ie without user interaction), you can do this? if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Use scrapy project as base for http based requests such as just logging in..

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "without user interaction"?
You can check for a valid user session (more [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/://)) and if no session available automatically redirect the user to the Login dialog.

There is also an unofficial SDK for Python, that you can [explore](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/third-party-sdks/#python).

Comment: I wish I could enter my username and password Directly in my code to activate a user session. My server has no user interface .. my server is a kind of proxy between my users and facebook.

Comment: Even if what you want is possible, it won't give users access to THEIR Facebook accounts but to yours!!

Comment: I do not understand how I can do:  I have to do some queries on facebook by my server: I created a token with app_facebook_id and SECRET_KEY, my server starts to make these queries using FQL but I get an error: I do not have an active session!
So how can I do this? I can use some information of the app facebook?  these FQL queries are not linked to users' personal information ready but, probabily, facebook needs an active session by a logged user (the caller) ... in my case the caller is my server

Comment: What are these queries? some data from facebook require a user token..other an app access token is enough. I suggest you go through the [different types of access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/) to better understand how Facebook operates.

Comment: select eid, uid, rsvp_status from event_member where uid = example_user_id

Answer (score 0):

You can give a look to this project I recently published: https://github.com/gsscoder/facebook-snooper.

Quite simple API:

```
from facebook_snooper import log_in, get_intro

if not log_in('some@user.com', 'some_password'):
    sys.exit('Can\'t login to Facebook!')

intro = get_intro('a.profile.id')
for info in intro:
    print(f'  - {info}')
```

You can also search profiles with `search_profile(query)` function.

Here a more complete example: https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/335e2397a4329167a7f373fb29349640.